# load data from hdfs into HIVE error path not found

Tags: hive, hdfs

I am facing an issue which I do not how to solve.
I have uploaded a csv file into hdfs under the paths /user/oscarvicenteremonhotmail/StockPrices.csv and /user/oscarvicenteremonhotmail/hdfshive/StockPrices.csv.
I have verified the files exist in HDFS in both directories
1692778942274.png
Then in the webconsole under hive instance:

I have created the DATABASE IN HIVE and the subsequent tables stock_prices , that'is correct.
When I try to load the data into the tables it continously says the filepath does not exist, it does not matter if I use local or without the local statement:

1692778826618.png
Is there an special way to reference to this path in HDFS which I am missing or a pointer to that path must be created?
Thanks for your help.

Hello good morning,
I am facing an issue which I do not how to solve.
I have uploaded a csv file into hdfs under the paths /user/oscarvicenteremonhotmail/StockPrices.csv and /user/oscarvicenteremonhotmail/hdfshive/StockPrices.csv.
I have verified the files exist in HDFS in both directories

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRqW6.png)
Then in the webconsole under hive instance:
I have created the DATABASE IN HIVE and the subsequent tables stock_prices , that'is correct.
When I try to load the data into the tables it continously says the filepath does not exist, it does not matter if I use local or without the local statement:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVay0.png)
is there an special way to reference to this path in HDFS which I am missing or a pointer to that path must be created?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with visibility. The latest screenshot doesn't display which user is operating beeline.

Please ensure that you're running beeline as the same user.

If not, you'll need to grant read-write (rw) permissions to both the file and possibly the folder as well.